# Custom android launcher goes back to default launcher on pressing back button

Tags: android, launcher

I am working on a launcher application. It is being show along with the default launcher on pressing the back button. However, wherever I am in my custom launcher or whether in the starting page of my launcher it self, when I press the back button, the screen navigates back to the default android launcher. I need help. 
This is the code I used to set my app as a launcher

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: If you go to Android settings can you see your app among the launchers you can choose from?

Comment: Yes, the launcher is working fine. I can navigate to other sub apps I created within the new launcher. However, on pressing the home button on any screen of the new launcher, the screen goes back to the default launcher home screen and the not the new,custom launcher home screen that i created

Comment: I haven't tried creating my own launcher, but when I installed Nova Launcher, upon clicking home button I got a dialog to choose which Launcher I wanted to use. I had to go to settings and set the Nova Launcher as default for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies. I really appreciated them.
Yes, it does pop the screen to choose. However, after making my custom launcher as default one, it shouldn't have navigated back to the default home screen

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. I meant the back button. When I am in the starting page of my custom launcher, it navigates back to the default android home screen

Comment: Well that might change some things - don't forget to change it in the title!

Comment: thank you. I did that. Sorry once again

Answer (score 6):

This seemed to work for me
**Kotlin**

```
override fun onBackPressed() {}
```

**Java**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {}
```

Comment: This indeed seems to solve it, when added to the launcher activity

Answer (score 0):

Those are categories for intents, `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` just means when you run the application it will launch the specified class

Comment: actually, even removing the following two codes the launcher works just fine.
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
however, I can't get it to stop the custom launcher to navigate back to home screen

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. I meant the back button. When I am in the starting page of my custom launcher, it navigates back to the default android home screen